# Remove frames from a video depending on black pixel ratio

Tags: ffmpeg, video, colors, video-editing, ffmpeg-filters

We have a surveillance camera recording taken at intervals of a month. It is necessary to remove the dark time of the day (night recordings) from the record or from the video file by deleting all frames with a black pixel ratio of more than 30%.

I perform the following steps:

- step 1 - speeding up all files attached to the directory `*.mp4`:

```
for %%i in (".mp4") do ffmpeg -i %%i -r 30 -filter:v "setpts=1/3600*PTC" "Output\%%i"
```

- step 2 - merge accelerated `*\Output` files into `*.mp4`:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c copy General(h_264).mp4
```

- step 3 - convert to H.265 codec `*.mp4`:

```
ffmpeg -i General(h_264).mp4 -vcodec hevc TimeLapse(h_265).mp4
```

- The solution came from @Gantendo - As a result, I get a *. mp4 file without 27% of frames exceeding 98% of black pixels. (I can only explain it this way):

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "blackframe=amount=0:threshold=98, metadata=select:key='lavfi.blackframe.pblack':value=27:function=less" -vsync 0 img%d.mp4
```

Comment: More detail is required, brand, model numbers, sample image

Comment: @RohitGupta I have an original and converted by me to Timelapse video file from the Hikvision recorder in h.264 codec 30 FPS mp4 resolution

Comment: Processing is carried out by ffmpeg

Comment: Hello, what did you try? You should also edit the question whenever you add more details.

Comment: @Destroy666 I perform the following steps.
step 1 (speeding up all files attached to the directory *.mp4):
for %%i in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i %%i -r 30 -filter:v "setpts=1/3600*PTC" "Output\%%i"
Step 2 (merge accelerated files into *.mp4) "*\Output":
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c copy General(h_264).mp4
Step 3 (Convert to H.265 codec *.mp4):
ffmpeg -i General(h_264).mp4 -vcodec hevc TimeLapse(h_265).mp4

Comment: Once again, please **edit the question** whenever adding more details (press the `Edit` link below it).

Comment: @Destroy666 I have made amendments. Did I do everything right?

Comment: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/22159/how-to-extract-only-frames-from-videos-that-have-certain-levels-of-luminosity  Пу́тин — хуйло́

Comment: @Destroy666 The method you proposed extracts a series of dark frames in *.jpg. I also need to remove dark frames from *.mp4 with saving *.mp4

Comment: I didn't propose anything. Your question is still not fully clear because of language, but it's close to being understandable and answerable now. Edit the 1st paragraph to be as clear and detailed as possible as to what exactly should be the criteria for cropping/deletion.

Comment: sorry for my English. From the video file, you just need to delete all frames with a black pixel ratio of more than 30 %